# Jenkins Docker container running out of space

Tags: docker, jenkins, diskspace

I'm running a standard Jenkins container, using docker-compose as following:

```
version: '3'
services:
  jenkins:
    container_name: jenkins
    image: jenkins/jenkins:lts
    restart: unless-stopped
    volumes:
      - jenkins_home:/var/jenkins_home
    ports:
      - 8080:8080
      - 50000:50000
volumes:
  jenkins_home:
```

When I run it, `/var/jenkins_home` runs out of space.

```
$ docker exec -it jenkins bash
jenkins@e7009fbca617:/$ df -h
Filesystem      Size  Used Avail Use% Mounted on
overlay          18G   17G   64K 100% /
tmpfs            64M     0   64M   0% /dev
tmpfs           495M     0  495M   0% /sys/fs/cgroup
/dev/sda1        18G   17G   64K 100% /var/jenkins_home
shm              64M     0   64M   0% /dev/shm
tmpfs           495M     0  495M   0% /proc/acpi
tmpfs           495M     0  495M   0% /proc/scsi
tmpfs           495M     0  495M   0% /sys/firmware
```

What I don't understand is what eats this space. If I go inside `/var/jenkins_home/` to see what uses the space, it doesn't show such usage:

```
jenkins@e7009fbca617:/$ cd /var/jenkins_home/
jenkins@e7009fbca617:~$ du -sh
3.5G    .
jenkins@e7009fbca617:~$
```

How to investigate what causes the issue?

Note: Jenkins indeed reports the system running out of space, so it's not functioning.

Note 2: I was trying to run a build for pretty large repository, maybe it could lead to some issues with the space. But I tried to remove the container and recreate it again and it doesn't help.

Comment: what does `du -hd1` say

Comment: jenkins@e7009fbca617:~$ du -hd1
8.0K    ./.groovy
16K     ./fingerprints
32K     ./logs
4.0K    ./nodes
8.0K    ./init.groovy.d
8.0K    ./userContent
4.0K    ./workflow-libs
105M    ./plugins
48K     ./secrets
28K     ./.java
1.9M    ./updates
108K    ./jobs
16K     ./users
88M     ./war
575M    ./workspace
2.8G    ./caches
3.5G    .

Comment: Well there you go, your workspace and caches are taking 6+ GB

Comment: But it still doesn't explain why 17G are used. Though I'll look at those too

Answer (score 0):

For us, we were building docker images from within the jenkins docker. As such, we need to run regular prunes from inside the docker image:

1. `sudo docker exec -it jenkins-blueocean bash`
2. `docker system prune -a`

This should remove all stopped containers, all networks not currently in use, all images without an associated container, and most importantly the build cache from WITHIN the docker image.

Hope this helps.